# Communicate with serlet in another project from appletviewer in netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, web, applet

I have in netbeans two projects. One with my web and with my servlet. Second project is named Applet and contains my applet(self signed applet) with classes which he needs to work. applet is added into  web project via packing options and works well in browser. I have a method which open URLconnection to servlet and send GET Request, servlet send response and i get inputStream in my aplet to jLabel text. All work good in browser but when i am trying it in Appletviewer it fire exception and in HTTP server Monitor does not  appear new GET request  to server which should occur when UrlConnection.getInputstream() is done., thats my problem? So Do exist any solution for connect to servlet from Appletviewer?

here is my method for getting text from servlet which run in composition with my web in browser but not if i run it via appletviewer

```
 URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/Rozhlas_jsf/SoundServlet?name=startSounds");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

// open a connection to the servlet
URLConnection servletConnection=null;
        try {
            servletConnection = url.openConnection();
            servletConnection.setDoInput(true);
            servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            // get the input stream from the servlet
            InputStream in = servletConnection.getInputStream();
           jLabel1.setText(convertStreamToString(in)) ;


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

and here is what occur when i  try it in applet viewer

```
 compile-single:
run-applet:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:8084" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:466)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at SoundApplet.SoundApplet.jButton5ActionPerformed(SoundApplet.java:683)
    at SoundApplet.SoundApplet.access$200(SoundApplet.java:44)
    at SoundApplet.SoundApplet$3.actionPerformed(SoundApplet.java:184)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

I today morning tryied change applet.policy file because i tried to solve this problem 
[my another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547986/self-signed-applet-running-in-browser-cant-copy-files-write-by-writer-encode)

I overwrote this

```
grant {

permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

by this

```
 grant {

    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>","write";
    };
```

and via it i lost permission to connect my Servlet from appletviewer. I just rewrite that back and all is fine. Sorry for needless topic but i was mad from that really.